# How to manually calculate fitted values in zero count models?

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I'm looking to see if I can manually calculate the fitted values for a Hurdle model (from the `pscl` package) to ensure I understand what's going on, but so far I can't get it to work.

Say you have model:

```
HurdleMod   <- hurdle(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dt, offset = log(x3), dist = "negbin")
```

and you get coefficients:

```
Count model
intercept: -4
x1: 18
x2: 3
log(theta): 1.5

Zero model
intercept: -1
x1: 100
x2: 1.6
```

I then try to calculate fitted values with a for loop

```
CountFit <- 0
ZeroOdds <- 0
ZeroProb <- 0

for (i in 1:length(dt$y)) {
  CountFit <- exp(-4+18*dt$x1[i]+3*dt$x2[i] + log(dt$x3))
  ZeroOdds <- exp(-1+100*dt$x1[i]+1.6*dt$x2[i]+ log(dt$x3)) 
  ZeroProb <- dt$ZeroOdds/(1+dt$ZeroOdds)
      dt$ManFit[i] <- CountFit*ZeroProb
}
```

But when I compare my `dt$ManFit` results with my `HurdleMod$fitted` results I'm getting different answers, which makes me think I'm misinterpretting how Hurdle Model fitted values are calculated.

How should I manually calculate Hurdle Model fitted values using the coefficients above?

Comment: You appear to be using the equation for the expectation in the zero-inflated model in the hurdle model...but these are not identical. See Equations (6) and (8), respectively, in `vignette(“countreg“, package = “pscl“)`.

Comment: @AchimZeileis thanks for your input, I'm still struggling to interpret the equations [imglink](http://imgur.com/a/BNBTw) however, and reproduce the fitted results. Does `fzero` represent `ZeroOdds` and `fcount` represent `CountFit`? I'm also unsure what the first variable in equation (6) of `xtBeta` represents and I can't locate a description of it.